# Remote control Android device via USB on a computer, device screen and sound must be transfered to the computer

Tags: android, usb

We are doing experiments with mobile phones in a shielded box.
No wireless/radio communication is possible, so we need to use an USB cable.

"androidscreencast" is working great to remote control an android device via USB.
Now it is necessary to get the sound of the device too while remote controlling it.
Is there any software available for this purpose?
The device is rooted.

In the worst case we'd have to use the headset port of the device.

Answer (score 2):

Check this one: [ShareKM](https://sites.google.com/site/droidskm/)
It has beta expired issue, but a xda developer released fixed version, [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51833757&postcount=170)

And this one: [MyMobiler](http://mymobiler.com/index.html)

I have not tried audio as you need, but you may give a try.

Comment: We are using androidscreencast and a plugged in headset. That combination works perfect for us. I previously called it "worst case" but it's comfortable enough.

Comment: I thought MyMobiler seemed more capable and suggested that. I dont know much about androidscreencast. Sorry

Comment: I've just installed MyMobiler. The instructions aren't great, but it works really well now that it's set up (I've tested the screen casting and remote control).